# CSS issue - difficulty in aligning

Tags: css

ok, here an image of my problem..
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s30wathhiqpky9e/help.JPG

The thing is that both of these are DIVs, same width but they just don't align together !!! how do I solve this problem. What i want is that they align together as if they are the same size...here's the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .div_top {
        height:50px;
        padding:5px;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:1100px;
        border:dotted;
        border-width:1px;
    }
    .div_top_ads {
        float:right;
        position:relative;  

    }

    #div_nav_bar{
        width:1100px;
        height:30px;
        margin:auto;
        opacity:10%;
        margin-top:auto;
        background-color:#CCC;

    }
    body {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .divme {
        width:100%; 

    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>


    <div class="div_top"> hello

      <div class="div_top_ads">Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div>

    </div>

    <div class="divme">
    <div id="div_nav_bar">yello!</div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: First Try removing padding and margin from both the divsand check if they are proper , I think it is because of padding and margin you applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.div_top { 
    height:50px; 

    margin:0 auto; 
    width:1100px; 
    border:dotted; 
    border-width:1px; 
} 
#div_nav_bar{ 
    width:1102px; 
    height:30px; 
    margin:auto; 
    opacity:10%; 
    margin-top:auto; 
    background-color:#CCC; 
border-width:1px; 
}
```

The problem with the alignment is 
the two divs are in different width because the one have border and other dnt have border.
also the padding increases the width by 10px.
Now youcan remove the padding and add 2px width to div_nav_bar or add 12px width.

The width is calculated padding+border + width

Answer (score 0):

Hey now issue is you used to padding + border

now change to your css as like this

your `#div_nav_bar` `width` is total `1100px  width + 10px padding left of right + 2px border` now total width is `width :1112px`

```
#div_nav_bar{
    width:1100px; // change to width:1100 + 10 + 2px; // width:1112px


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ppvTJ/)**.

What I did is just remove all the `padding` you applied and also the `border`.

I gave `width:1100px` to both the divs.

The issue is when you apply `padding` to a element its `width` becomes `width+padding-left+padding-right`.

Hence the div seems to appear more wide.In your case you gave `padding`  and `1px border` to your upper `div(div_top)`.

Hence its `width` was calculated as `1100px` + `padding-left`+`padding-right`+`border-left`+`border-right`.